# How can i query multiple objects, filtering with multiple id's

Tags: django, querying

```
class Timeline(models.Model):
license = models.ForeignKey(License, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
last_renewed = models.DateField()
due_date = models.DateField()


def home(request):
title = "Licences"
agencies = Agency.objects.all()
agent =Agency.objects.get(pk=1)
licenses = License.objects.all()
for license in licenses:
    print(license.id)
    timeline = Timeline.objects.select_related().filter(license_id = license.id).order_by('-id')[:1]
```

I want to display at least one timeline related to each of the licenses that i am querying

Answer (score 0):

instead of the forloop you can do something like this.sorry for my english but `at least one` means i think one or more.but this will give you nothing or more because it might be a case where no timeline is related to a license so `an empty` queryset.

```
def home(request):
        title = "Licences"
        agencies = Agency.objects.all()
        agent =Agency.objects.get(pk=1)
        licenses = License.objects.all()
        timeline = Timeline.objects.select_related().filter(license__in =licenses).order_by('-id')
```